# Windows c++ struct with Bit field, packing

Tags: struct, bit-fields, pack

```
union AP
{
    UCHAR bin[28];
    struct{
    ULONGLONG TA    :42;
    UINT St     :6;
    UINT Reserved1  :3;
    UINT fo     :4;     
    UINT P          :9;

    UINT cy :17;
    UINT Reserved2  :3;
    UINT A  :12;

    UINT Fg :8;
    UINT P2         :24;

    UINT Fp     :10;
    UINT SChNum :22;

    UINT ItAdrs:32;

    UINT IEAdrs:32;

}stt;
```

I want to use stt when stt's size is 28 byte.
but This code's size of stt is 32byte.
I think this code's needs "packing" because of 'ULONGLONG TA:42'.

```
#pragma pack(push,1) 
#pragma pack(1)
```

both code didn't work.
how to packing struct that has bit field symbol.
I create my code on visual studio 2012 with c++, windows7

Answer (score 0):

The C/C++ standards allow the compiler to insert padding between bitfields when the base types of the bitfields are different. So the padding is likely coming between your ULONGLONG and the subsequent UINT. Try splitting your ULONGLONG into two UINT members; that should eliminate the padding.

Comment: and then Is it okay
    temp_AP.stt.TA = ( CurrTA ) & 0xFFFFFFFF; 
    temp_AP.stt.upperTA = ( CurrTA >> 32 ) & 0x3FF; ?

Comment: You don't need to do the `&`, unsigned overflow is appropriately defined by the standard already.